# Object not declaring, void not showing in class

Tags: c++

I made a simple program in an attempt to understand composition. I looked over the program a bunch of times but I cant see why my "birthobj" isn't being declared and my "printDate()" isn't being declared. I would really appreciate if any of you could offer some insight.

- Composition.cpp

  ```
       #include <iostream>
       #include "Birthday.h"
       #include "People.h"
       using namespace std;

      int main()
      {
          Birthday birthObj(11,21,1996);
          People brandanBalasingham("Brandan", birthobj);
          brandanBalasingham.printinfo();
      }
  ```
- birthday.h

  ```
     #ifndef BIRTHDAY_H
     #define BIRTHDAY_H


     class Birthday
      {
          public:
              Birthday(int m, int d, int y);
              void printDate();
       private:
              int month;
              int day;
              int year;
      };

      #endif // BIRTHDAY_H
  ```
- birthday.cpp

  ```
      #include "Birthday.h"
      #include <iostream>
      using namespace std;

      Birthday::Birthday(int m, int d, int y)
      {
             month = m;
             day = d;
             year = y;
      }

      void Birthday::printDate()
      {
           cout << month << "/" << day << "/" << year << endl;     
      }
  ```
- people.h

  ```
     #ifndef PEOPLE_H
     #define PEOPLE_H
     #include <string>
     #include "Birthday.h"
     using namespace std;

     class People
     {
         public:
             People(string x, Birthday bo);
             void printInfo(); 
       protected:
       private:
              string name;
              Birthday dateOfBirth;
     };

      #endif // PEOPLE_H
  ```
- people.cpp

  ```
      #include "People.h"
      #include "Birthday.h"
      #include <iostream>
      using namespace std; 

      People::People(string x, Birthday bo)
      : name(x), dateOfBirth(bo) // name = x, dateOfBirth = bo
      {
      }

      void People::printInfo()
      {
           cout << name << " was born on ";
           dateOfBirth.printDate();
      }
  ```

Compiler message:

```
'birthobj' undeclared (first use of this function)
'class People' has no member named 'printInfo'
```

Answer (score 2):

You defined the variable `birthObj` but used `birthobj`. Note that in C++ identifiers are **case-sensitive**. Simply change your code to

```
People brandanBalasingham("Brandan", birthObj);
//                                        ^
```

and it'll work. Of course, the same goes for `printInfo` vs. `printinfo`.

Comment: It worked thanks! I did the same thing with printInfo!